# Netstream and Video in ActionScript 2 not working

Tags: flash, red5, actionscript-2

I have to add the WebCam support to an existing VoIP client-server application. This application was developped using Flash MX and Red5.

I followed the way the previous coder thinked :

When he captured the stream from the Microphone,
i captured the stream from the webcam.

When he received the audio signal from a network stream,
i tried to receive the video signal from the same network stream.

I used the function `attachVideo()` on the outgoing netstream. (Sender side)
And attachVideo(inputNetStream) on the Video Object on the scene (Receiver side)
But it doesn't work...

Why is it not working ? 
Where do the problem come from ?

Comment: Does neither of the NetStream endpoint clients show video?

Answer (score 0):

I am not usually one to find fault in matters seemingly unrelated to the issue at hand, but it surprises me each and every time when people first thing post their immediate questions without comprehending the [relevant parts of the ActionScript 3.0 Reference by Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html) first, available by a straightforward Google search:

> `public function attachNetStream(netStream:NetStream):void`
>
> Specifies a video stream to be displayed within the boundaries of the Video object in the application. The video stream is **either a video file played with NetStream.play(), a Camera object,** or null. If you use a video file, it can be stored on the local file system or on Flash Media Server. If the value of the netStream argument is null, the video is no longer played in the Video object.

> `public function attachCamera(camera:Camera):void`
>
> Specifies a video stream from a camera to be displayed within the boundaries of the Video object in the application.
>
> **Use this method to attach live video captured by the user to the Video object**. You can play the live video locally on the same computer or device on which it is being captured, or you can send it to Flash Media Server and use the server to stream it to other users.

The above implies that when you want to display the publishing stream (or simply a camera image), you use `attachCamera`, while for streams playing published content you use `attachNetStream`. Additionally, and it is also documented by the reference pages, you can use `Camera.setLoopBack(true)` call to make the local camera match what the other party would be looking at (the so called 'loopback mode'), with regards to latency, blocking artefacts, fps etc.